# How to Get First and Last Day of a Quarter in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I need to rewrite code from SQL server to Vertica.

`SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` - i need to get first date of quarter

`SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0))`- last date

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH 
input(the_date) AS (
          SELECT CURRENT_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-05-03'
)
SELECT
  the_date
, TRUNC(the_date,'q')::DATE                   AS begin_quarter
, LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(the_date,'q'),2)) AS end_quarter
FROM input;
-- out   the_date  | begin_quarter | end_quarter 
-- out ------------+---------------+-------------
-- out  2020-03-23 | 2020-01-01    | 2020-03-31
-- out  2020-05-03 | 2020-04-01    | 2020-06-30
```

Comment: @Victoria_Dunham . . . I would recommend `date_trunc()` over `trunc()` because it is more explicit on what it does.  But they do the same thing.